# posting Url from dropdown without 'submit' button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my view, I have dropdownlist:

```
@Html.DropDownList("InnerId", Model.GroupDropDownList, new { @class = "select_change" })
```

I would like to be able to submit the value when the user just clicks on the selection rather than selecting and using a submit button.  I created the following script to try do this, but it won't accept the value of my variable `dropdownValue` as it just says `doesn't exist in current contect`

```
$('.select_change').change(function () {
    var dropdownValue = $('.select_change').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"@Url.Action("Group","EditMembers", new { @innerid= dropdownValue})"
    })
})
```

Please note this question is cobbled together from various other similar questions and answers but I haven't been able to get any of the other similar questions on stack to work for me. Therefore please do not mark this question as duplicate as I really need some help with my specific example. Thanks.

Comment: `@Url.Action()` is razor code which is evaluated on the server before its sent to the view. `dropdownValue` is a javascript variable which does not eve exist at that point (its not in scope)

Comment: right, any suggestions how I would pass the innerId parameter then?

Comment: Use `@Url.Action("Group","EditMembers)` to generate the base url, and then append `'&innerid=' + dropdownValue`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I think the only solution is by using javascript/jquery. am I right?

Comment: @Alex, Yes, javascript is the only way to react to client side events (but this is a bad idea and not a recommended UI)

Comment: So behind the scenes, web forms autopost is also done via javascript. so you are saying should we refrain using UI that uses autopost back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is a possible solution for it...**

```
$('.select_change').change(function () {
var dropdownValue = $('.select_change').val();
var url = '@Url.Action("Group","EditMembers")';
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: {'innerid':dropdownValue }
    })
})
```

Comment: I was thinking of the same solution.

Comment: this looks great, but for some confusing reason I get a 404 not found error.  When I copy the link address and paste it in the address bar it works.  It's very odd. Here is the error in the console:  jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5 POST http://localhost:8050/my-tennis-club/161/group-edit 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Ah I  found the reason for the 404 error, it's a GET method, not POST.

Comment: well it almost worked, it's now hitting the right action with the right parameter, gets the all the correct data in the model and then for some reason refuses to render the view.  I've given up now and am just going to use a submit button instead.

Comment: In the end it was so easy just using a bootstrap dropdown with a href for each list item. http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns